# Removing punctuation and placing it at the end of a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that upon execution will remove punctuation marks from a word and place the mark at the end. The removal bit was working fine until I appended the part which adds that same mark at the end; now instead of removing the punc. inside of the string, it leaves it there *and* adds it to the end, which is not what I want. My code is the following:

```
function containsPunctuation(word) {
    var new_word;
    new_word = word.replace(".", "");
    new_word = word.replace("!", "");
    new_word = word.replace(";", "");
    new_word = word.replace(",", "");
    new_word = word.replace("?", "");
    if (word.includes(".") === true) {
        new_word = new_word + ".";
    }
    return new_word;
}
```

Comment: new_word = word.replace("?", ""); This just makes it have the . back

Comment: Can you provide input and the expected output strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main issues with your code:

---

### 1

After the first replacement you have to operate on `new_world`

```
var new_word;
new_word = word.replace(".", "");
new_word = new_word.replace("!", "");
```

or more simply you may operate directly on the received parameter without using an additional variable:

```
word = word.replace(".", "");
word = word.replace("!", "");
```

---

### 2

keep in mind that `replace()` replaces only on the first occurrence.

If it's not the desired behaviour you may use this function:

```
function StringReplace( str, fnd, rep ) {
    return str.split(fnd).join(rep);
}
```

then

```
    word = StringReplace( word, ".", "");
    /* ...and so on */
```

---

### 3

Whether the string includes a punctuation mark `.` or not must be checked before you start the replacement (and remove every `.`) So at the beginning...

```
var addPunctuation;
addPunctuation = word.includes(".");
```

then before the function returns:

```
if( addPunctuation ) {
    word += '.';
}
```

---

### The whole thing becomes

```
function StringReplace( str, fnd, rep ) {
    return str.split(fnd).join(rep);
}

function containsPunctuation(word) {
    var addPunctuation;
    addPunctuation = word.includes(".");

    word = StringReplace(word, ".", "");
    word = StringReplace(word, "!", "");
    word = StringReplace(word, ";", "");
    word = StringReplace(word, ",", "");
    word = StringReplace(word, "?", "");

    if( addPunctuation ) {
        word += ".";
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Although that is also a problem, its not the main problem here

Comment: @juvian you're right. It took some time but I think I spot them all

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regular expression for replacing unwanted characters?

```js
var string = 'a,b;c!d.e?f';

string = string.replace(/[.,;!?]/g, '') + '.';

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code here, the line  `new_word = word.replace(".", "");` is replacing the string new_word with the expected value from word (without the .)
The variable word though, is not actually having the . removed, but just the value you are setting to, new_word.  So when the replace for ! comes, the value word in word.replace still contains the . from the first replace because it was only replaced in new word.  So something like this would work in your scenario, could be improved but just a point of concept.

```
function containsPunctuation(word) {
        var new_word;
        new_word = word.replace(".", "");
        new_word = new_word.replace("!", "");
        new_word = new_word.replace(";", "");
        new_word = new_word.replace(",", "");
        new_word = new_word.replace("?", "");
        if (word.includes(".") === true) {
            new_word = new_word + ".";
        }
        return new_word;
    }
```